# Socket.io websocket not working on Google Cloud Virtual Machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, websocket, socket.io

I created a game of rock paper scissors with a 5-minute timer. The timer is handled via socket.io. We tried setting up Socket.io using WebSocket.

Backend:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  },
  transports: ['websocket'],
});
```

Frontend

```
socketIO.connect(apiURL, {transports: ["websocket"], upgrade: false});
```

I get alot of errors on my virtual machine but not on localhost. Here's the image of the errors:

[image]

But these errors don't happen if I initialize my socket.io like this:

Backend:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  },
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
});
```

Frontend:

```
socketIO.connect(apiURL);
```

The reason I wanted to use WebSocket instead of polling is due to polling floods the browser with socket.io requests/responses every second iteration of the timer. It comes to a point where my timer goes to a complete stop (possibly due to an overload of socket.io activity). Is there a way I could make WebSocket work on GCP Compute Engine VM, remove those pesky errors, and make the timer work?